# Gradle buildTypes + flavors - providers and GCM

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

**====PROBLEM====**

I am trying to allow the installation of both `debug` and `release` versions on one device.
My app is made of few modules and I have 3 flavors. All of these modules have different packages in their manifest. The way I'm dealing with my `ContentProviders` is:

```
 <provider
        android:name="com.myapp.testapp.modules.mailboxes.MailboxesProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider.MailboxesProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:multiprocess="true" >
 </provider>

private static final String AUTHORITY = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider.MailboxesProvider";
```

And it looks like its ok but when I am trying to install second one(debug) I get error `[INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]`, also whenever I install the first one(release) there is info about problem with GCM persmissions even tho I am changing its package accordingly:

```
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

**====QUESTION====**

Is `applicationId` enough to deal with all different packages?
Why I'm getting GCM errors even tho I change the package info?